# How to write url for testing when using viewsets in Django Restframework

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am really noebie for testing. Actuall, I dont know how to write test url for getting response from viewsets.
This is my views,

```
class AppraisalAPI(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Appraisal.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = AppraisalSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action in ['retrieve']:
            self.permission_classes = [IsHRUser | IsManagementUser]
        elif self.action in ['list']:
            self.permission_classes = [IsUser]
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_permissions()

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        data = instance.summary()
        return Response(data)
```

This is my urls.py,

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('appraisal', AppraisalAPI)
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

This is my test function,

```
 def test_appraisal_api_readonly(self):
 url = reverse('appraisal-list')
        self.client = Client(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
        resp1 = self.client.get(url, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(resp1.status_code, 200)
```

This test url only went inside list action. when i give detail insteadof list it went only retrieve action.
Here, I want to get Retrive function response, How can i get after getting permission i want to receive retrive function response.
Anyhelp Appreciable,..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use the `DefaultRouter`, you can trigger the `retrieve` action with `appraisal-detail`, and use a primary key of the object, so:

```
def test_appraisal_api_readonly(self):
    url = reverse('appraisal-detail', kwargs={'pk': some_pk})
    self.client = Client(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
    resp1 = self.client.get(url, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(resp1.status_code, 200)
```

with *`some_pk`* the primary key (`.pk`) of some item you construct in the test.